# Why Ether balance is 0 after 5 airdrops?

Tags: ether, wallets

I created an ether wallet to join some airdrops and 5 of this airdrops sent me tokens but in my ether wallet the balance is 0 (zero). I don't understand why. 
I was searching tutorials but I could not find any answer.

If I check here: https://ethplorer.io/address/0x1be0b8c0e389ad74b0b36cb91e89bfcab874c128 I can see the 5 transfers to my eth wallet with 0 balance.

Answer (score 1):

Your address has zero ether, because no ether were transferred to it.  Though it has [some tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0x1be0b8c0e389ad74b0b36cb91e89bfcab874c128).

Ethereum address may have many different assets on it and ether is just one of them.  Though, ether is quite special, because it the the only type of asset, that can be used to pay transaction fees of Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I thought the ether were transferred to my wallet. Kind regards and thanks again !